# Using Eclipse, I get an error "Variable" cannot be resolved or is not a field and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It occurs in the MainActivity.java portion and there are no errors in any other folder. I have tried everything I could find and saw that it is a bug in Eclipse but sometimes it is the fault of the programmer. I'm not sure which this case is for me. "Variable" in this case is for any line with R.id."variable".

```
package com.example.tipcalculator1;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    OnEditorActionListener, OnClickListener {
// define instance variables for the widgets
EditText billAmountEditText;
TextView percentTextView;
Button percentUpButton;
Button percentDownButton;
TextView tipTextView;
TextView totalTextView; 


// define an instance variable for tip percent
float tipPercent = .15f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    billAmountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billAmountEditText);
    percentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentTextView);
    percentUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.percentUpButton);
    percentDownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.percentDownButton);
    tipTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipTextView);
    totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);

    // set the listeners
    billAmountEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    percentUpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    percentDownButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    // calculate the tip and display the results
    calculateAndDisplay();
}

public void calculateAndDisplay() {
    // get the bill amount
    String billAmountString = billAmountEditText.getText().toString();
    float billAmount;
    if (billAmountString.equals("")) {
        billAmount = 0;
    } else {
        billAmount = Float.parseFloat(billAmountString);
    }

    // calculate tip and total
    float tipAmount = billAmount * tipPercent;
    float totalAmount = billAmount + tipAmount;

    // display the results with formatting
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    tipTextView.setText(currency.format(tipAmount));
    totalTextView.setText(currency.format(totalAmount));
    NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    percentTextView.setText(percent.format(tipPercent));
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    calculateAndDisplay();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.percentDownButton:
        tipPercent = tipPercent - .01f;
        calculateAndDisplay();
        break;
    case R.id.percentUpButton:
        tipPercent = tipPercent + .01f;
        calculateAndDisplay();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Your `R` class is not being generated, probably due to a bug in one of your resources or in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: If not try to clean and build your project.

Comment: I tried clean and build and I got in error in main.xml...error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings')...what does that mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may

1. Go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > tab [Order and Export] > Tick Android Version Checkbox, and then Properties again > Build Project .
2. Mistakes in your `xml` views could cause the R.java not to be generated. Go through your view files and make sure all the xml is right

Go to your `string.xml` under `res\values` add one line

`<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>`

such that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Hello Map</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: by android version you mean the version to which I am compiling to, because there is no box for those exact words

Comment: adding that one line worked. can you tell me why I needed to do that and what it means?

Comment: Sure, you may check here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String